# Write Excel formula into cell using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, reference

I am trying to overwrite wrong Excel formula.

I copied the formula from the cell into the code and placed double quotes.

Already read that I have to type two times " for getting a " into the formula. I can't tell what is really going on, because of companies compliance but the code should do it.

Imagine there are 180 components with the same 18 function in cells. By deleting some components I lost the reference and instead of writing every formula again, I try to do this with VBA.

```vb
Sub nachtrag()

Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim Start As Integer
    Start = 4
Dim Bezug As Integer

For i = 0 To 179
    Bezug = Worksheets("QK-Daten").Range("R" & ((i * 18) + 18) + Start).Value
    For j = 1 To 17
    Worksheets("QK-Daten").Range("Z" & j + (i * 18) + Start).Value = "=WENN(R" & Bezug & "="""";"""";SVERWEIS(R" & Bezug & ";'QK-Tabelle'!$B$3:$C$123;2;FALSCH))*(R" & j + (i * 18) + Start & "/R" & Bezug & ")+((N" & j + (i * 18) + Start & "+O" & j + (i * 18) + Start & ")*0,3+(P" & j + (i * 18) + Start & "+Q" & j + (i * 18) + Start & ")*0,1)"
    Next j
    Worksheets("QK-Daten").Range("z" & ((i * 18) + 18) + Start).Copy
    Worksheets("QK-Daten").Range("z" & ((i * 18) + 18) + Start).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you try writing the formula on the range, or the formula result? For the first variant, please replace `.value` with `Formula` and `FALSCH` with `FALSE`. VBA does not care about localization. Or try using `FormulaLocal` and keep localization...

Comment: oh sry, maybe i had to write my code in english. Its actually German. sry for that. Yeah its the first one i try. And i changed it like you said, but still doesnt work. Also changed "=wenn..." into "=if...", but no difference.

Comment: Really often asked (and answered) here. My advice: Write the correct formula into Excel manually, go to the VBA editor and dump the formula into the immediate window (`? ActiveCell.Formula`). This will show you how Excel expects the formula to look like. Also, don't write the formula directly into the cell, use an intermediate variable, that helps debugging. In your case, you need to replace the `;` with an `,` as a separator for the formula parameters.

Comment: I did, and then something weird is happening: original its "...$R$22.." but vba created this: "...R22C18...". Also changed "..R16/$R$22.." into "..R[1]C[-14]/R22C18.." where are the secound letters coming from?

Comment: Got it. Problem solved. For someone who has the same Problem, here the code to check: 

`Worksheets("QK-Daten").Range("Z" & j + (i * 18) + Puffer).Value = "=IF(R" & ((i * 18) + 18) + Puffer & "="""","""",VLOOKUP(R" & ((i * 18) + 18) + Puffer & ",'QK-Tabelle'!$B$3:$C$123,2,FALSE))*(R" & j + (i * 18) + Puffer & "/R" & ((i * 18) + 18) + Puffer & ")+((N" & j + (i * 18) + Puffer & "+O" & j + (i * 18) + Puffer & ")*0.3+(P" & j + (i * 18) + Puffer & "+Q" & j + (i * 18) + Puffer & ")*0.1)"`

i edited some variable's, but Rules to get the function should be clear.

Answer (score 1):

Try writing the formula with placeholders in the string and then use `Replace()` to substitute the values.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub nachtrag()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, cell As Range, s As String
    Dim Bezug As Long, Start As Long
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, r As Long
    
    ' formula
    Const F = "=IF(R<bezug>="""";"""";VLOOKUP(R<bezug>;'QK-Tabelle'!$B$3:$C$123;2;FALSE))" & _
              "*(R<r>/R<bezug>)+((N<r>+O<r>)*0,3+(P<r>+Q<r>)*0,1)"
    
    Start = 4
    Set ws = Worksheets("QK-Daten")
    With ws
        Set cell = .Range("R" & Start)
        For i = 0 To 179
            Bezug = cell.Offset(18).Row 'Value
            For j = 1 To 17
                r = j + (i * 18) + Start
                s = Replace(F, "<bezug>", Bezug)
                s = Replace(s, "<r>", r)
                cell.Offset(j, 8).Formula = s 'Z
            Next j
            
            ' not sure what this is doing
            ' .Range("z" & ((i * 18) + 18) + Start).Copy
            ' .Range("z" & ((i * 18) + 18) + Start).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues
            cell.Offset(18, 8).Value = cell.Offset(18, 8).Value
            
            ' next component
            Set cell = cell.Offset(18)
           
        Next i
    End With
    
    MsgBox "Done", vbInformation
End Sub
```

Comment: In the rows 1 to 17 in each component i need a formula. The last cell has sometimes an manually value inserted, and sometimes its based on an old formula. So i just copy the value and paste it just as a number in the cell to get rid of the formulas.